# which framework is best for Selenium Webdriver

Tags: frameworks, selenium, webdriver

I'm starting using Selenium webdriver to write auto test scripts for an ajax website mainly on Chromedriver by using JAVA.  The website is coded by using HTML 5. it's actually a website mainly used on mobile devices like iphone, android.

I don't know which framework to choose. I saw TestNG, JUnit. And someone suggested me to use Fitness.

I'm confused on choosing a proper framework.

Can anyone give me some suggestions? thanks in advance.

Comment: note that there are also Selenium WebDrivers to automate Android and iOS though I don't know if they run as stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question on opinions, there's no definite answer. You should go with the framework that fits you best.

[JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) is generally (from my point of view) considered more standard to Java testing and is usually integrated to Java IDEs, but [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) has some advanced features one might like (and its integration is usually very easy, too). [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/) is a different story, the tests in it are written quite differently. In JUnit and TestNG, you write the test cases in plain Java, but FitNesse works ... different. And it's by far the least common.

All those frameworks work well with Selenium, you [can find examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=webdriver%20junit%20example) on [all of them](https://www.google.com/search?q=webdriver%20testng%20example) all [over the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=webdriver%20fitnesse%20example).

If you're really just starting with WebDriver and Java, go for JUnit, as it's usage won't limit you for a very long time and it's [quite easy to begin with](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm).

Comment: hi, Slanec, thank you for your response. I googled a few before, it is usually said JUnit or TestNG. but my boss wanted me to use Fitness, I'm really not sure if Selenium webdriver can be well integrated with Fitness. I personally prefer to TestNG or JUnit.

Comment: I'm just confused about will it really work by using Fitness?  I haven't seen many examples about Fitness and Selenium webdriver. Most examples are TestNG and JUnit.

Comment: @user1488025 Edited into the answer. JUnit is used the most, then TestNG, then FitNesse. All of them work well, however, so investigate those libraries a bit to see what they're capable of, and pick teh one that suits your needs best.